# How to solve Error 403 when scraping a webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am scraping information from a list of published properties. When I run my code, it seems like the page has an anti-scraping system.

The code is supposed to open each propertie's link, scrape the data I need, and then move on to the next one. My previous problem was that it didn't scrape all the data from each page, but now it won't open the page because of the 403 error. My code is the following:

```
import scrapy
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests  # Asegúrate de tener instalada la librería requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class ScrapingClubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraping_club"

    # Inicializa un DataFrame y una lista para cada atributo
    data = {"ID": [], "Coordenadas": [], "Region": [], "Comuna": [], "Barrio": [],
            "Precio_UF": [], "Precio_Pesos": [], "Metros_Cuadrados_Totales": [],
            "Metros_Cuadrados_Utiles": [], "Num_Piezas": [], "Num_Baños": [],
            "Captado_Por": [], "Nombre_Captador": [], "Tiempo_Publicado": []}

    def start_requests(self):
        # Pregunta al usuario si es venta o arriendo
        venta_arriendo = input("¿Deseas buscar venta o arriendo? (venta/arriendo): ").lower()

        # Pregunta al usuario el tipo de propiedad
        tipo_propiedad = input("¿Qué tipo de propiedad buscas? (casa/departamento/otro): ").lower()

        # Pregunta al usuario la región
        region = input("¿Qué región buscas? (metropolitana, valparaiso): ").lower()

        # Construye la URL en función de las respuestas
        url = f"https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/{venta_arriendo}/{tipo_propiedad}/propiedades-usadas/{region}"

        # Abre la URL y comienza el scraping
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = response.request.meta["driver"]
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        try:
            for page_number in range(1,3):
                # ... (código existente)
                # Espera a que se carguen los productos
                wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".andes-card.ui-search-result.ui-search-result--res.andes-card--flat.andes-card--padding-16.andes-card--animated")))

                for product in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".andes-card.ui-search-result.ui-search-result--res.andes-card--flat.andes-card--padding-16.andes-card--animated"):
                    item = {}
                    item['id'] = product.get_attribute('data-view')  # ID de la propiedad
                    item['coordinates'] = product.get_attribute('data-lat') + ', ' + product.get_attribute('data-lon')  # Coordenadas
                    item['region'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-item__location span:nth-child(1)").text  # Región
                    item['comuna'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-item__location span:nth-child(3)").text  # Comuna
                    item['barrio'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-item__location span:nth-child(5)").text  # Barrio
                    item['price_uf'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".price-tag-fraction").text if product.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".price-tag-fraction") else ''  # Precio en UF
                    item['price_clp'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-price__second-line .price-tag-fraction").text if product.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-price__second-line .price-tag-fraction") else ''  # Precio en CLP
                    item['total_area'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-card-attributes .ui-search-card-attributes__attribute:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2)").text  # Metros cuadrados totales
                    item['usable_area'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-card-attributes .ui-search-card-attributes__attribute:nth-child(3) span:nth-child(2)").text  # Metros cuadrados útiles
                    item['bedrooms'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-card-attributes .ui-search-card-attributes__attribute:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(2)").text  # Número de piezas
                    item['bathrooms'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-card-attributes .ui-search-card-attributes__attribute:nth-child(5) span:nth-child(2)").text  # Número de baños
                    item['captured_by'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-list__item .ui-search-result__content-wrapper .ui-search-item__group .ui-search-item__group--seller .ui-search-item__seller-info .ui-search-item__seller-name").text  # Captado por
                    item['capturer_name'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-list__item .ui-search-result__content-wrapper .ui-search-item__group .ui-search-item__group--seller .ui-search-item__seller-info .ui-search-item__seller-subtitle").text  # Nombre del captador
                    item['published_time'] = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-search-list__item .ui-search-result__content-wrapper .ui-search-item__group .ui-search-item__group--seller .ui-search-item__group--price .ui-search-item__group__element .ui-search-item__highlight-label").text  # Tiempo publicado
                    print(item)
                next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".andes-pagination__link.ui-search-link")))
                next_button.click()

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error general: {str(e)}")

        # Después de iterar todas las páginas, crea un DataFrame y guarda en CSV
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)
        df.to_csv("datos_scraping.csv", index=False)
        self.log("Datos guardados exitosamente en datos_scraping.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve the error under *normal* circumstances. You have communicated with the server correctly– it just does not want to work with you. In more formal terms, "[the HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)"

One thing to note is that if you visit the link in a browser and you don't receive the error, but you receive the error when using your script, it is probably a `User Agent` issue. If this is the case, you would change the following:

First, create your header:

`headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.3'}`

Then, change

this: `yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)`

to this: `yield scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)`

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting target website through Chrome browser, see which headers are being sent with individual request types and then add them with Scrapy. Often, a single header element resolves the issue without further debugging.